# Error con mysql_fetch_array: espera un recurso pero recibe booleano

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este error en mi código:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ... on line ...

Parece que es la sintaxis de la línea de sql array, pero no veo cómo solucionarlo. ¿Sabe alguien cuál es el problema?

Aquí mi código:

```php
<div class="section">
<?php
$numCedula = htmlentities($row['NumCedula'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = {$numCedula}";
$result = mysql_query($sql) ;
//echo [$result];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?>
    <div class="mis_afiliados_1">
        <a> 
            <img src="<?php echo $row['avatar'];?>" alt="Avatar" /><br>   
            <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?><br>
            <?php echo date('d/m/Y',$row['signup_date']); ?>
        </a><br>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba a incluir la conexión a la base de datos en el mysql_query y de paso le pones un die error por si lanzara algún error saber que tipo es: `$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die("Error en: $sql: " . mysql_error());`

Comment: Lo hice y me sale este error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Quiero advertir que estás usando una función declarada obsoleta: `mysql_query()`, ver: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php Y ello porque consultar la base de datos con ella pone en riesgo tus datos, haciéndolos vulnerables de Inyección SQL, ver: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php Entiendo que a veces uno tiene prisa por resolver un problema y no se detiene a ver problemas mayores. Tal y como estás usando tu SQL, si es en un sitio en línea cualquiera podría borrar todas las tablas de tu BD poniendo sólo esto al lado de `numCedula`: `1; DELETE FROM tabla;`

Comment: Wow muchas GRacias Cedano.. no estaba al tanto de eso.. pero, como podría resolver mi problema entonces? en este caso?

Comment: He creado una clase para conexiones PDO. Es muy fácil de usar, si quieres puedo ayudarte si te decides por implementar ese tipo de conexión, la cual, junto que MySQLi es la más segura y son las dos formas de consulta de BD recomendadas por PHP. Dale una ojeada a esto (https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO) y si te interesa me dices.

Comment: Estás seguro que $numCedula no es un string? A lo mejor debieras entrecomillarlo

Answer (score -1):

No te está devolviendo datos
[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

> Devuelve un array de cadenas que corresponde a la fila recuperada, o
>   FALSE si no hay más filas.

Prueba así:

```
$numCedula = htmlentities($row['NumCedula'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = " . $numCedula;
```

Si te sigue fallando comprueba que $numCedula esté obteniendo correctamente el dato que buscas.

Comment: Hola probé con esa oipcion y me sale este error: SELECT * FROM users WHERE Patrocinador = 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: No soy partidario de este uso y tampoco recomiendo su uso, pero el usuario es el que ha preguntado por qué no funciona eso... y yo intento dar una respuesta al por qué su error, en cambio tú lo que haces es dar valoraciones negativas y decir que es peligroso, totalmente de acuerdo, si te ves capaz de solucionarlo explícale al usuario en 2 partes: 1º por qué su código no funciona y cómo solucionarlo y 2º le explicas que lo que hace es peligroso y de nuevo cómo solucionarlo... aquí buscamos resolver nuestras dudas, no criticar las respuestas de otros sin tan siquiera dar una solución.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo PriNcee y estoy muy agradecido con tu aporte ..sin embargo todavia sigo dando tumbos.. sé que el problema es sencillo en realidad pero es que sinceramente no logro ver que es lo que me falta.. y si pues por ahora como estoy nuevo en sql estoy es probando .. y pues obviamente luego necesitaria ya mejorar el codigo para mayor seguridad.. ahorita lo que yo quiero es hacer y aprender en realidad..

Comment: Si la consulta te está devolviendo eso es porque $numCedula está vacío. Esa variable de dónde la recoges?? No será un $_POST['NumCedula'] en vez de $row['NumCedula'] ??

Comment: @Jesunday _ahorita lo que yo quiero es hacer y aprender en realidad_ Precisamente por eso, aprender algo que está obsoleto y que no funcionará en las próximas versiones de PHP no te sirve de nada. Sería mejor aprender a usar PDO y MySQLi, no es tan complicado, tus datos estarán seguros y ganarás tiempo. No le veo sentido a aprender algo que no te servirá en el futuro. Saludos.